Import without appending v=? parameter?
Consider the following index.html:
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.12.4/brython.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.12.4/brython_stdlib.js">
    </script>
</head><body>
<script type="text/python">
    from pyflate2 import gzip_main
</script>
<pre id="output">Loading...</pre></body></html>

I ran http.server, directed my browser to localhost:8000 and got the following in the Firefox console:
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2024 17:48:52] "GET /pyflate2/__init__.py?v=1726760932019 HTTP/1.1" 404 -

The file doesn't exist, because I couldn't predict the v= parameter. Is there a way to change brython's behavior so that it doesn't append it?

I searched Brython issues here:
https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues?q=is%3Aissue+import++timestamp+is%3Aclosed
I found the following comment:
https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues/1266#issuecomment-568259074
Here's a copy of it:

In the commit referenced above I have added an option "cache" to the brython() function, eg :
<body onload="brython({debug: 1, cache: true})`

This removes the query string in the Ajax calls that load external scripts (<script type="text/python" src="script.py">) and those that import modules.
Does it solve the issue ?

That solves my problem.
